# Проблема с Bitmap изображениями полученными с веб камера их обработкой в списке и создание из них видео с помощью Accord.Video.FFMPEG

Tags: c#, aforge

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Threading;

using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace Camera
{
    class Class1
    {
        static List<Bitmap> array_image_bitmap = new List<Bitmap>();
        static int width;
        static int height;
        static int frameRate;

        private static void Main()
        {
            FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
            width = videoSource.VideoCapabilities[videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length - 1].FrameSize.Width;
            height = videoSource.VideoCapabilities[videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length - 1].FrameSize.Height;
            frameRate = videoSource.VideoCapabilities[videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length - 1].AverageFrameRate;
            if (width > 1920) width = 1920;
            if (height > 1080) height = 1080;
            if (frameRate > 30) frameRate = 30;

            videoSource.NewFrame += VideoSource_NewFrame;
            videoSource.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            videoSource.SignalToStop();
            videoSource.WaitForStop();
            videoCreate("путь до папки\\video.avi", array_image_bitmap.ToArray());
        }

        private static void VideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame, width, height);

            array_image_bitmap.Add(bmp);
        }

        private static void videoCreate(string outputFileName, Bitmap[] inputImages)
        {
            using (VideoFileWriter videoWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
            {
                videoWriter.Open(outputFileName, width, height, frameRate, VideoCodec.H264, bitRate: 5000000);

                foreach (Bitmap image in inputImages)
                {
                    videoWriter.WriteVideoFrame(image);
                }
                videoWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Я хочу получать видео с веб камеры и записывать это в видео файл, но в у меня проблема в том, что этот код "съедает" слишком много памяти, за 10 секунд спокойно на это уходит ~2гб оперативки. Как я понял, виноваты Bitmap в списке, которых там может становится пару сотен за те же 10 секунд.
Я решил эту проблему путем сохранения каждого Bitmap'а в файл и вызовом у него .Dispose(), но мне совсем не подходит такой вариант, особенно из-за сильного снижения скорости получения изображения с камеры.
Если есть люди использующие другие методы получения видео с камеры, был бы рад их изучить, но это единственный способ который я нашел. У остальных библиотек нет хороших документаций, а видео по ним ничего не объясняют.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(10000);` спать - плохая привычка. Найдите другой способ ожидания окончания работы метода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начну с мелочей.

`array_image_bitmap.ToArray()` - конвертировать `List<T>` в массив - это тоже затраты времени и памяти. Не нужно этого делать!
Метод `videoCreate` должен принимать параметр `List<Bitmap> inputImages`, тогда конвертация в массив становится не нужна.
А если учесть, что нужна всего лишь итерация по этой коллекции в цикле `foreach`, то ещё лучше сделать параметр типа `IEnumerable<Bitmap>`.

---

Имя `array_image_bitmap` я бы заменил на `bitmaps`.

---

Свойство `Frame` класса `AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs` имеет тип `Bitmap`. Поэтому не нужно копировать его, создавая ещё один экземпляр изображения `new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame, width, height)`.
Впрочем, если нужно менять размер кадра, то это может быть необходимо.

Я не знаю, что происходит внутри этой библиотеки. Если `Frame` диспозится автоматически, то добавлять его в `List<Bitmap>` нельзя. В этом случае можно писать его в файл прямо в событии `VideoSource_NewFrame`.

---

А вообще, как мне кажется, следует создать и открыть `VideoFileWriter` заранее и просто использовать его в событии:

```
private static void VideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    videoWriter.WriteVideoFrame(eventArgs.Frame);
}
```

В этом случае становится не нужен ни промежуточный список, ни сохранение в файлы изображений.
Возможно, от создания битмапа с нужными размерами не избавиться, если только этот `VideoWriter` сам на лету не умеет изменять размер кадра.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за проделанный анализ, получив ответ вроде всё понятно становится, но догадаться сам не смог!